# second ajax call does not trigger

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 ajax call , One for dropdown population from `listplace.php` and another for when I click on a selected item it has to pull details from `dataprod.php` But my problem is the second ajax call does not even trigger on change event.

Even when I `echo 'triggered'` it does not display from change event.
I hope its bcoz of a simple mistake I did. Please help!!

```
<select id="name">
  <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
</select>

<?php if (isset($_GET['place']) && $_GET['place'] != '') { ?>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {place: '<?= $_GET["place"] ?>'},
            url: 'listplace.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                if (json.option.length) {
                    var $el = $("#name"); 
                    $el.empty(); // remove old options
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.option.length; i++) {
                        $el.append($('<option>',
                            {
                                value: json.option[i],
                                text: json.option[i]
                            }));
                    }
                }else {
                    alert('No data found!');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>


<script>
$("#name").on('change',function (e) { 
  var name1 = this.value;
  $.ajax ({
     data:{name1: name1},
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'dataprod.php',
     success: function (response) {
         console.log(response);
         $('.products-wrp').html('');
         $('.products-wrp').hide();
         $('.products-wrp').html(response);
         $('.products-wrp').show();            
     },
    });
</script>     
<?php } ?>
```

dataprod.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); //start session
    include("config.inc.php"); //include config file
?>
<?php

    $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
    echo $name1;
    echo 'triggered';
    $results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT product_name, product_desc, product_code,  
    product_image, product_price FROM products_list where product_name='$name1'");

    $products_list =  '<ul id ="products_list" class="products-wrp">';
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products_list .= <<<EOT
    <li>
    <form class="form-item">
    <h4>{$row["product_name"]}</h4>
    <div>
    <img src="images/{$row["product_image"]}" height="62" width="62">
    </div>
    <div>Price : {$currency} {$row["product_price"]}<div>
    </form>
    </li>
    EOT;
    }
    $products_list .= '</ul></div>';
    echo $products_list;
?>
```

Comment: Why you included jquery twice `jquery-3.2.1.min.js`? And use `$("#name").on('change',function (e) {`
 instead of `$(document.body).on('change',"#name",function (e) {`

Comment: Why did people downvote this ? Some people are so quick to judge !!

Comment: @RohanKumar I changed it and seen and corrected some other significant changes but I am not getting the result .. its still blank

Comment: @LillyMeow check in console for any errors when AJAX request call is made.

Answer (score 2):

You have an syntax error in the `onChange` event. `})` is missing at the end.

Try this :

```
$("#name").on('change',function (e) { 
    var name1 = this.value;
    $.ajax ({
        data:{name1: name1},
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'dataprod.php',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('.products-wrp').html('');
            $('.products-wrp').hide();
            $('.products-wrp').html(response);
            $('.products-wrp').show();            
        },
    });
});
```

Also put the jquery library in the head section once

Comment: should I include  data:{name1: name1} as data:{name1: 'name1'}

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
$(document.body).on('change',"#name",function (e) {
```

remove .body so you end up with $(document)

Comment: $("#name").on('change',function (e) { is wrong. If you want to use it this way, you have to define: $("#name").change( function(e) { ... }) but this will not work if you load 'names' dynamically.

Comment: is there something I can do it for dynamic loading?